# Path to File Outside WWW

Tags: php, lamp

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10743881/1303216

I'm currently working off of this.  I copy and pasted the code and have been tinkering to get it to work.  On the webroot of my server there is a folder called secretfolder.  In public_html there is a PHP file with the script to fetch my hidden PDF (copied code).  The problem is, the files keep coming out corrupt and when I look at them in Notepad, I get

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/user/public_html/herp.php
```

How do I get it to point outside of public_html.  I don't entirely understand relative file paths so some help would be great.

I'm on a standard LAMP

**Short Question**

What would the relative file path be from a PHP file in Public_html that needs to point to /secretfolder that is directly on the webroot?

Side note, I didn't just try $file = '/path/to/file/outside/www/secret.pdf'; but I need to know what that is supposed to be in actual use.

## Update

The file path I was using was /secretfolder/Pay%20Stub%20View.pdf

%20 (Spaces) for some reason was breaking it.  It works fine now.  I feel kind of dumb.  Can anyone explain why this happens?  All I know is that it does.

Comment: You could always use absolute URLs, if that's an option. Something like `/home/user/secretfolder/file.pdf`

Comment: It's still tossing me a jenky file.

Comment: And you are sure that you are using the correct absolute path to a valid PDF file?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

I do not know the layout of your file system. But PHP/Apache has access to the lot (assuming right file permissions). I tend to use relative paths as you can then easily transfer from development to production/testing environments without the hassle.

**Longer answer**

Is there a file `/home/user/public_html/herp.php` on the server?

To answer the other question, relative paths use the `..` notation for directories. It means the sub-directory - the branch below. Just view the file system as a tree. The leaves are the files. The various branches are the directories. To reach the directory/branch holding up your current directory/branch - use the `..` notation.

You can even get to the trunk if you so desire!
Hope that helps.