# Embedding a PDF into a website without a SRC attribute

Tags: php, pdf, mime-types

Currently working on an offshoot of the idea more adequately addressed here.
[Creating a Secure File Hosting Server for PDFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743850/creating-a-secure-file-hosting-server-for-pdfs)

I'm developing a secure PDF hosting website where certain users can download certain PDF's that I have stored outside of the webroot to prevent people from accessing documents they shouldn't access.

I've got the download working using the first solution, but I want to implement a 'view/preview' feature too.  I still don't get content headers as well as I should but I believe what is causing the bulk of my issues is I can't put a 'src' attribute on the embed/object/iframe/whatever.  And that's kind of the point of the system.

My question is, is there any way to feed a file (as opposed to a url) to an embed/object?  I would like to keep my current system and I'm going for simplicity at the moment so the easier the better.

I saw [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/best-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html) and will probably check out pdf.js if I'm trying something that isn't doable.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet had the chance to play with pdf.js, but it either that or a flash player of some sort.

Or you rely on the browser to display it has a webpage and you can iframe it, but that's so lame... it would work only for a fraction of you users.

Answer (score 0):

`PDF2SWF` - convert PDF to SWF ( 1 page = 1 SWF).

Use other SWF (reader) to load SWF pages via XML or something else.

Use `$_SESSION` to store ID of PDF document which should be served through e.g. `/preview` (same link for previewing all documents)

Don't serve original PDF, put a watermark, or make them low-res.
Otherwise, your PDF will never be "secure".

**http://www.swftools.org/**