# Is HTTP REFERER safe enough?

Tags: php, http

I have a **PHP file** which contains some important data of my website. I have set up the below written HTTP REFERER script in that file. For now its only accessible when redirected from a specific page of my website backend (which is password protected). Is it safe to assume that this file cannot be accessed by any other means?

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://yoursite.com/IMPORTANT_FILE.php") {
        // continue
    } else {
        header("Location: http://yoursite.com/");
        exit(); //Stop running the script
        // go to form page again.
    }
?>
```

Comment: No, it can easily be set to anything you want using a number of browser plugins.

Answer (score 6):

No. `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` [can be spoofed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing) so it cannot be relied upon for safety or accuracy. [This chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/referer-control/hnkcfpcejkafcihlgbojoidoihckciin?hl=en) makes it trivial for a newbie to do.

A better way to do this is authenticate your users before they attempt to access your protected files. Only after passing this authentication can they access them. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743850/creating-a-secure-file-hosting-server-for-pdfs/10743881#10743881) for an example.