# How to get previous page url from where user get redirected

Tags: php, payu

I have a simple online shopping website and i want to ensure that the user is coming from the payment page not open the success page directly. I am using PayuMoney

Comment: Lots of ways to do this but some are easily spoofed. What research have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this example of someone asking a similar question:
[Creating a Secure File Hosting Server for PDFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743850/creating-a-secure-file-hosting-server-for-pdfs/10743881#10743881)

Redirecting in most ways is unreliable and can be spoofed easily.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.